# Redis container - Returning a timeout after a while

Tags: python, docker, redis, celery

I'm running a set of services, that use redis as a queue, broker. Like celery.

When I start my containers (using docker-compose) everything works just fine, but after a "while" the services trying to connect to redis throw a Timeout exception.

This are my redis container logs:

```
1:C 09 Jan 15:10:30.407 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 09 Jan 15:10:30.408 # Redis version=4.0.11, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 09 Jan 15:10:30.408 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
1:M 09 Jan 15:10:30.411 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:M 09 Jan 15:10:30.411 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
1:M 09 Jan 15:10:30.411 # Server initialized
1:M 09 Jan 15:10:30.411 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
1:M 09 Jan 15:10:30.412 * Ready to accept connections
1:M 09 Jan 16:10:48.695 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
1:M 09 Jan 16:10:48.731 * Background saving started by pid 19
19:C 09 Jan 16:10:48.738 * DB saved on disk
19:C 09 Jan 16:10:48.739 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
1:M 09 Jan 16:10:48.833 * Background saving terminated with success
```

I'm using the default config, this is its docker-compose section:

```
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
```

And this is the exception I'm getting from my flask/ celery container:

```
kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: Timeout connecting to server

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 241, in apply_entry
    result = self.apply_async(entry, producer=producer, advance=False)
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 358, in apply_async
    entry, exc=exc)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vine/five.py", line 178, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 350, in apply_async
    **entry.options)
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 535, in apply_async
    **options
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 745, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 436, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vine/five.py", line 178, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 431, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    yield
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 744, in send_task
    self.backend.on_task_call(P, task_id)
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 265, in on_task_call
    self.result_consumer.consume_from(task_id)
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 126, in consume_from
    self._consume_from(task_id)
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 132, in _consume_from
    self._pubsub.subscribe(key)
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2482, in subscribe
    ret_val = self.execute_command('SUBSCRIBE', *iterkeys(new_channels))
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2404, in execute_command
    self._execute(connection, connection.send_command, *args)
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2408, in _execute
    return command(*args)
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 610, in send_command
    self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 585, in send_packed_command
    self.connect()
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 486, in connect
    raise TimeoutError("Timeout connecting to server")
```

What could be wrong?

If I could never connect I understand, but the problem starts after a while and it returns a timeout forever until I restart the container.

Thanks!

Comment: are you exposing the redis port? can you share your docker-compose file

Comment: Those two lines are the redis config, I'm not explicitly exposing the port because I'm only connecting from the containers. And it works when I start them, for a while, but after some hours... apparently they get a timeout... with no error logs in redis

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a iptables rules mess up between docker rules and some other rules.
The I fixed it is by using Nginx as a reverse proxy (gateway pattern) and managing access rules on it instead of using iptables for that.

This way everything works as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post how you managed access rules with nginx? Thanks.